# Ajax CORS failed over ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: javascript, https

I do request Ajax CORS from one of my domain ran over HTTPS to call a webservice on my subdomain. my google chrome console throw that error `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`. what is going on? is there something i should change in the ajax request, or something i should do in the server config?